# Как правильно организовать endpoint для фильтра?

Tags: symfony, symfony3

Есть **Entity Product**

id, title, price
1   car    100
2   bus    300

Есть **Entity Options**
id, product_id, name, value
1   1           color red
2   1           city  london
3   2           color green
4   2           lang  eng

Мне нужно сделать endpoint в котором с фронта приходит выбранные фильтра, цена и options - по ним отдать данные про продукт.

Вопрос в том как это правильно организовать?

Например, сделаю функцию getByOptionAndPrice() и в post буду передавать такое:
**get-by-option-and-price
?product['price']=100;500&option['lang']=eng,option['color']=reg;green**

Выходит что мне будет приходить массив, а как правильно в форма валидировать такое? Ведь нет ArrayType для формы.